# Oracle XML Report File Size Issue

Tags: oracle, xls, bi-publisher, oracle-ebs, xlsb

The xml report generates a huge file (xls) of arounf 800 MB- 1 GB. The system hangs when trying to open the file. Tried opening a 400 MB xls file and saved it as xlsb which reduced the file size to 4.5 MB. Is there a way to generate the output in xlsb format instead of default xls. Oracle Apps version is 12.2.6.

Comment: It sounds like you're using Oracle E-Business Suite, and trying to get more compressed Excel reports using XML Publisher (ie, BI Publisher). Is that right?

Comment: Sounds like your query is collecting too much data. Have you made sure it’s correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use E-text templates to produce a comma separated value (csv) file. It’s usually used for EFT transfers for banks. But you can make it do whatever you want. Since it’s only text, it won’t have any of the formatting markup that an BI publisher would add to an Excel file. You can then open it up in Excel and do what you wish with it.

Comment: Tried printing the text output ,pipe separated columns. Notepad crashed while opening the file which had around 0.5 million rows.

Comment: Microsoft notepad is not good for large files. Try notepad++ (https://notepad-plus-plus.org) if you want to open the file you created. Else, you can open in Excel too. How's the file size?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, BI Publisher can not do it and Oracle has an enhancement request logged for this: [Bug 24545689](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=bug&id=24545689) : BI PUBLISHER EXCEL .XLSX TEMPLATE

For large data exports from Oracle EBS into native .xlsx format, you can use a third party solution such as our Blitz Report: [www.enginatics.com/faq/#how-does-blitz-report-compare-with-oracle-bi-publisher](https://www.enginatics.com/faq/#how-does-blitz-report-compare-with-oracle-bi-publisher)

It is free for limited use.